# Show that $ \{f^1,f^2,f^3\}$ forms a linearly independent set.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $x_1<x_2<x_3$ be three real numbers. Let $P_2$ be the linear space of all 2nd degree polynomials.

Consider the following  linear functionals:

$f^1: \ f^1(p)=p(x_1), \\ f^2: \ f^2(p)=p(x_2), \\ f^3: \ f^3(p)=p(x_3), \ $

where $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2 \in \mathcal{P_2}$.

Show that $ \{f^1,f^2,f^3\}$ forms a linearly independent set.

Also show that $\{f^1,f^2,f^3\}$ forms a spanning set for the dual space $P_2^*$.

**Answer:**

we have to find a basis $ \{p_1,p_2,p_3 \}$ of $P_2$ such that $ \ f^j(l_i)=\delta^{j}_i , \ i,j=1,2,3$.

Then,

$f^1(p_1)=\delta^1_1=1 \\ \Rightarrow p_1(x_1)=1 \\ \Rightarrow a_1+b_1x_1+
c_1x_1^2=1$.

$f^2(p_1)=\delta^2_1=0 \\ \Rightarrow p_1(x_2)=0 \\ \Rightarrow a_1+b_1x_2+c_1x_2^2=0$.

$f^3(p_1)=\delta^2_1=0 \\ \Rightarrow p_1(x_2)=0 \\ \Rightarrow a_1+b_1x_3+c_1x_3^2=0$

We have to evaluate $a_1,b_1,c_1$ .

But I think I am proceeding in wrong direction.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $p_1(x)=c_1(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$ for some suitable value of $c_1$.